# Kubernetes Pod - Unable to set env variable from shell script

Tags: bash, shell, kubernetes

I have my java based application (built from ubuntu image) hosted in kubernetes pod. I'm having problems with declaring env variables from the shell scripts running when the pod starts. However I'm able to set env variables successfully from configmap and Dockerfile.
Below are the following syntax that I have tried and failed so far.

```
export testvariable=testvalue
export adminuser=$(az keyvault secret show --name myuser --vault-name mytestkeyvault | jq -r .value)
ADMIN_PASS3="$(az keyvault secret show --name myuser --vault-name mytestkeyvault | jq -r .value)"
```

None of the above worked and I don't see these variables in `printenv` too. However the values I pass from configmap through the deployment yaml are assigned perfectly and are displayed in the `printenv` too.

```
env:
        - name: sampleenvvar
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: my-config
              key: sampleenvvalue
```

What can be the cause of this weird behavior?
***Note:** The filesystem in the pod is read-only and write operation is allowed only in mounted volumes.*

Comment: Do you have a more complete example?  How is this script getting run?  How are you verifying the variables are or aren't getting set?  (If the image's entrypoint script runs these `export` commands, they will be accessible to the main container process, but neither the Kubernetes metadata nor exec-type debugging shells will show them.)

Comment: @DavidMaze I exec into the pod and ran the script again in the running containers and then did a `echo $testvar`. Nothing was printed. As mentioned already in the question, I tried `printenv` too and that did not display these env variables too.

Comment: I'd avoid `kubectl exec` here for a couple of reasons.  You can't change the main process's environment; you can only affect one replica at a time; if the cluster decides to delete and recreate a pod it won't see your manual changes.